# Jhipster sort and filter a table

Tags: jhipster

I'm new to the universe of Jhipster, I wonder if it is possible to add filters in the jhipster tables (entities) , for example: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/ or 
http://ng-table.com/#/ . ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes of course, anything that works with angular 2+, you can also add ag-grid https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Merci for your reply, I tried before adding the ag-grid, but without success. Do you know where I can get an example with a Jhipster app, or do you have any tips?

Comment: No but you should search for examples using Angular 2+ and webpack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular, you can use the JHipster Angular `sort.directive.ts` and `sort-by.directive.ts` like so...

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="ascending" [callback]="methodThatOrdersTBodyRows.bind(this)">
            <th jhiSortBy="id"><span>ID</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="title"><span>Title</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="description"><span>Description</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Your `<tbody>` should render rows of data provided by the controller using the `*ngFor` directive for convenience. Whenever a filter arrow is clicked, the `jhiSort` directive will update your `predicate` component variable to match the value of provided to the `jhiSortBy` directive, and it will toggle the `ascending` component variable to true and false. You should use the predicate and ascending variables in the callback (referenced as `this.predicate` etc.) to reorder (or re-query with a sort parameter) the arrays of row data rendered by the `*ngFor` directive.